# How do I share apps with my kids in Android 10?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, android-10, multi-user, paid-apps

I upgraded the family tablet from a HUDL2 to a Teclast P20HD. In the HUDL (Android 4.4.2) when I bought/installed new apps I was given the option to share them with other (restricted) users on the tablet. When I clicked on the user in the user settings, I got a list of installed apps that could be enabled/disabled for each user (my kids). This system was simple and effective.

With the Teclast (Android 10) I only have the option to add and delete users. No app control whatsoever.

I setup a Google account for my youngest (5yo) which I can manage through family Link (as I do with my older child's devices) but then there is no way to share apps from my own Google account to his (the family library feature is only for teenagers and won't cover the apps I've already purchased anyway). I have purchased dozens of kids apps over the last couple of years and I obviously want these available in my son's account.

I tried sharing apps with the Family Link feature inside the play store app on my account, but of the 100+ apps I've purchased, only 19 got shared.

I tried adding a second Google account from inside my son's tablet user space (my own Google account, so I could get the apps again on the play store with my credentials), but it won't let me; expecting all further accounts inside that user to be my kid's school accounts and such.

So I'm stuck. Is it possible to get the kids apps I have purchased into my son's user space on this tablet?

If not, is it possible with some other tablet (I could send this one back and get something different) or is the KitKat way of things now deprecated and I'm stuck with having to re-purchase hundreds of pounds of kids apps?

Comment: The app sharing system of your old tablet was something proprietary added by the manufacturer of the tablet. Your new tablet doesn't have such a modification, the multiple-user system is just plain Android.

Answer (score 1):

Robert is correct. Damn. I tried multi-user on different device and it's just as plain.

For anyone coming here from Google, I have further information and a couple of solutions..

Firstly, you can now setup child accounts at google for under 13s and, once added to the family group, they can legitimately access apps from your main account, so long as you setup Family Library and manually enable it for *each* app on the app's play store page (as mentioned, only 19 apps came over automatically when I first enabled this - I mistakenly believed this was the sum total of eligible apps). This is tedious but works but once enabled, future purchases can be added automatically (in your Family Library preferences at the Play Store).

This also works for apps that were "purchased" for free, during sales in the last five years.

Note: At the time of writing, setup of Google Family Library still states that users must be over 13 to receive apps, but this is evidently no longer true.

Before realising all this, I deleted my son's Google account from the new Android user, then used my own Google account to quickly install all the apps (from my Play Store apps list). Once done, replaced my account with my son's and we're in business.

Except with a different tablet. This rubbish-with-no-sensors is going back. If you came here considering buying a Teclast P20HD, I recommend you reconsider.